# Prove that $f(x) = x^2 - 1$ is continuous

Tags: functions

I need to show that $\lim _{x\to \:x_0}\left(x^2-1\right)\:=\:x^2_0-1$

Let $\epsilon > 0$, I get

$\left|x^2-1-\left(x_0^2-1\right)\right|\:=\:\left|x+x_0\right|\left|x-x_0\right|$

I can't choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{|x+x_0|}$, so what do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You may choose $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/(1+2|x_{0}|)\}$. Because then $|x+x_{0}|=|x-x_{0}+2x_{0}|\leq|x-x_{0}|+2|x_{0}|\leq 1+2|x_{0}|$.

Comment: So $delta$ can depend on $x_0$ but not on $x$?

Comment: Yes, here $x_{0}$ is fixed, not the variable $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** By using the ***Triangle Inequality***, you'll get :

$$|x+x_0||x-x_0| \leq (|x| + |x_0|)|x-x_0|$$